Google Sheets API - Bolding and Highlighting text
I am using the Google Sheet API. My code is working as expected. Now though, I want to add some bolding, highlighting, etc. I have reviewed other pieces of code but I am not fully understanding how to do this. Thank you!!
$service = new \Google_Service_Sheets($client);
$spreadsheetId = 'xxxxxxx';
$spreadsheet = $service -> spreadsheets -> get($spreadsheetId);
$result = $db -> query("SELECT * from xxxxxx");
$oldref = '1';
if ($result -> num_rows > 0) {
  $rows = array();
  $i = 0;
  while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
    $i++;
    if ($oldref != $row['refnumber']) {
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
 ////this is where I want to BOLD the $row['refnumber'] value.//////       
 $newRow = [$row['refnumber']];
  array_push($rows, $newRow);       
    }
  
  }
  $valueRange = new \Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange();
  $valueRange -> setValues($rows);
  $range = 'Sheet1';
  $options = ['valueInputOption' => 'USER_ENTERED'];
  $service -> spreadsheets_values -> update($spreadsheetId, $range, $valueRange, $options);

}


There is no shortage of Google docs covering this API. What have you tried? What isn't working?

@AlexHowansky Yes there are tons of documentation. I couldn't figure out how to insert it into my code. I found other documentation and will re-write code based of that information.

From this is where I want to BOLD the $row['refnumber'] value. in your script, I guessed that you wanted to set the bold to all values of $rows. In this case, how about the following modification?
In order to change the text format of the cell, "Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate" is used.
Modified script:
Before you use this script, please set $sheetId. In your script, from $range = 'Sheet1';, the sheet ID is the sheet ID of "Sheet1".
From:
$service -> spreadsheets_values -> update($spreadsheetId, $range, $valueRange, $options);

To:
$service -> spreadsheets_values -> update($spreadsheetId, $range, $valueRange, $options);

// --- I added the below script.
$sheetId = 0; // Please set your sheet ID.
$startRow = 0;
$rowLength = count($rows);
$colLength = count($rows[0]);
$requests = [new \Google\Service\Sheets\Request([
    "repeatCell" => [
        "cell" => ["userEnteredFormat" => ["textFormat" => ["bold" => true]]],
        "range" => [
            "sheetId" => $sheetId,
            "startRowIndex" => $startRow,
            "endRowIndex" => $startRow + $rowLength,
            "startColumnIndex" => 0,
            "endColumnIndex" => $colLength,
        ],
        "fields" => "userEnteredFormat",
    ],
])];
$req = new \Google\Service\Sheets\BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest(["requests" => $requests]);
$service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($spreadsheetId, $req);


When this script is run, the values in the cells from row 1 to the length of $rows are set as the bold type. From your showing script, all cell values of $rows are set as the bold type. If you want to set it to the specific cell values, please modify the above request body.

In the case of your script $service -> spreadsheets_values -> update($spreadsheetId, $range, $valueRange, $options); with $range = 'Sheet1';, the values are put from "A1". So, I used this modified script.

If you want to change the start row to set the bold, please modify $startRow to fit your situation.


References:

Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate
RepeatCellRequest

